# Google Apis Client Generator Python Not Running

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to execute Google APIs Client Generator to build new ADMIN-SDK for Java Language however I'm stuck in the generator, I've tried step by step using python2.6 and python2.7 both had similar outputs.

```
$ python $(/bin/pwd)/googleapis/codegen/generate_library.py --api_name=plus --api_version=v1 --language=java --output_dir=/tmp/gen --language=java
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/alejacquet/Development/git/google-apis-client-generator/src/googleapis/codegen/generate_library.py",
>   line 245, in 
>       app.run()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_apputils-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/google/apputils/app.py",
>   line 216, in run
>       return _actual_start()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_apputils-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/google/apputils/app.py",
>   line 244, in _actual_start
>       really_start()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google_apputils-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/google/apputils/app.py",
>   line 203, in really_start
>       sys.exit(main(argv))   File "/Users/alejacquet/Development/git/google-apis-client-generator/src/googleapis/codegen/generate_library.py",
>   line 152, in main
>       language_variant=FLAGS.language_variant)   File "/Users/alejacquet/Development/git/google-apis-client-generator/src/googleapis/codegen/generate_library.py",
>   line 179, in Generate
>       language_variations = Targets().VariationsForLanguage(language)   File
>   "/Users/alejacquet/Development/git/google-apis-client-generator/src/googleapis/codegen/targets.py",
>   line 68, in **init**
>       files.GetFileContents(self.targets_path))   File "/Users/alejacquet/Development/git/google-apis-client-generator/src/googleapis/codegen/json_with_comments.py",
>   line 54, in Loads
>       return json.loads(stripped, **kw)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py",
>   line 326, in loads
>          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py",
>   line 366, in decode   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py",
>   line 382, in raw_decode ValueError: Expecting property name: line 9
>   column 9 (char 198)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to specify `--language_variant=XXX`, where `XXX` is one of the directory names under `.../templates/java`